# Is python deepcopy more efficient than custom code, or less efficient/predictable?

Tags: python

I have a dict where the values are non-nested lists (specifically, the keys are ints and the values are lists of ints). I'd like to make a deep copy of it so that I don't modify the lists in the original dict.

I know I can use

```
copied = copy.deepcopy(original)
```

However since I know the form of the data structure I can also use something like

```
copied = {key:valuelist[:] for (key,valuelist) in original.iteritems()}
```

Is one of these solutions better? More efficient? Less likely to lead to nasty surprises?

I have been told that deepcopy() comes with some gotchas but I don't really understand what. I would also like to understand whether using deepcopy() is less efficient than my code (maybe because it's a more general solution?) or more efficient (maybe it's optimised at a lower level?).

Comment: Have you actually tried both solution to see which one is faster?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not even sure of good ways to time python code. I know about the time command in ipython. Using that makes me think deepcopy is a lot slower for my specific case (IF I'm testing it right) - but does that mean it's slower for similar cases? An answer based on understanding why it ought to be slower would still be valuable to me.

I'd also really like to know if there are reasons other than efficiency to avoid using it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you might have expected, `copy.deepcopy` is way slower than your second solution:

```
$ python -m timeit "original = {x: range(10) for x in xrange(10)}; copy = {x: v[:] for x,v in original.iteritems()}"
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.41 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit "original = {x: range(1000) for x in xrange(1000)}; copy = {x: v[:] for x,v in original.iteritems()}"
100 loops, best of 3: 17.1 msec per loop

$ python -m timeit "import copy; original = {x: range(10) for x in xrange(10)}; c = copy.deepcopy(original)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 86.4 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit "import copy; original = {x: range(1000) for x in xrange(1000)}; c = copy.deepcopy(original)"
10 loops, best of 3: 1.4 sec per loop
```

The reasons why `deepcopy` is so much slower than the dict comprehension + list copy are:

- `deepcopy` is multi-purpose function - it works for mostly any kind of object
- `deepcopy` is implemented in python whilst dict comprehension and list slicing is done at lower level

**And most imporantly**

- `deepcopy` makes copies of the elements inside containers recursively, whilst your dict comprehension **does not**.

Example:

```
>>> import copy
>>> obj = object()
>>> original = {x: [obj] * 10 for x in xrange(10)}
>>> copy1 = {x:v[:] for x,v in original.iteritems()}
>>> copy2 = copy.deepcopy(original)
>>> copy1[0][0] is original[0][0]
True
>>> copy2[0][0] is original[0][0]
False
```

As you can see, `deepcopy` copied the `obj` contained in the `original` so that `copy2` lists contain it's copy, not the `obj` itself. Unlike your dict comprehension, which preserves elements in the lists whilst created new list objects.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. In this particular case I know that the lists will not contain anything other than immutable types, but it's good to know what's going on under the hood for the future.

I'd still like to know if there are any non-efficiency-related reasons to avoid deepcopy. Are there cases where its behaviour could be surprising? Possibly the reason no-one's commented on this is that there aren't...

Comment: And.. is there any way to delete my 'extra' comment above? Stackoverflow apparently won't let me delete or edit because I left it for more than 5 minutes. It's just clutter though.

Answer (score 2):

I used below code, and get some result

```
import copy
import time

def go(loop):
    original = {x: [y for y in range(x)] for x in xrange(100)}
    print loop

    start = time.time()
    for x in xrange(loop):
        copied = copy.deepcopy(original)
    print 'deepcopy %ss' % (time.time() - start)

    start = time.time()
    for x in xrange(loop):
        copied = {k: v[:] for (k,v) in original.iteritems()}
    print 'custome  %ss' % (time.time() - start)

    print ''

for x in (100, 1000, 10000):
    go(x)


result

100
deepcopy 0.47200012207s
custome  0.00699996948242s

1000
deepcopy 4.69200015068s
custome  0.0620000362396s

10000
deepcopy 47.7449998856s
custome  0.677999973297s
```

obviously, `copy.deepcopy` is much worse. I think it handle much more than the custom method

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use `deepcopy` for now, if it turns out to be too slow you can always replace it with a custom function.

It might get slow if your dict is really really big, but as long as you don't work with really big data I won't worry too much.